# Estimating coefficients in softmax model formulations

Tags: statistics, optimization

Suppose we model $P[X=l]$ for some data using a softmax formulation, say :

$$ 
   P[X=l]=\dfrac{e^{\gamma_l}}{\sum_{i=1}^L e^{\gamma_i}}
$$

Now I have read some papers where they constraint the parameters $\gamma_i$ such that $ \sum_{i=1}^L \gamma_i =0$ and then optimise for these parameters. What is the rationale behind this formulation? Is this a fairly standard practice? Any other details will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $\gamma_i \leftarrow \gamma_i + c$ for an constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ does not affect the probabilities. Therefore, the constraint $\sum_i \gamma_i = 0$ presumably is meant to remove these duplicate solutions (you can use any other constant apart from zero to achieve the same effect).